# JS Replace return original string

Tags: javascript, regex

```
link = link.replace("/0/g", pos);
```

The link is "/PageEditor/Edit/10/0", and pos is 487. Replace function doesnt work for this.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes for [a regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) :

```
link = link.replace(/0/g, pos);
```